# How to accept lowercase characters in the search for completion in an entry function of a combobox

Tags: python-2.7, gtk3

This code (below) with comboboxentry do not match all completion 
exemple with the last two item : (S or P or F characters...)
(python v2.7.15 + GTK3)

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Name:     module1_TEST
# Python :  2.7.15
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def main():

    # -- Import Gtk3 packages
    import gi
    gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
    from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

    ldivers = [
        'http://www.google.com',
        'http://www.google.com/android',
        'http://www.greatstuff.com',
        'http://www.facebook.com',
        'S002.0002',
        '01-311P1015H5_F011650'
        ]
    liststore = Gtk.ListStore(str)
    for s in ldivers:
        liststore.append([s])

    completion = Gtk.EntryCompletion()
    completion.set_model(liststore)
    completion.set_text_column(0)

    entry = Gtk.Entry()
    entry.set_completion(completion)

    def match_anywhere(completeur, entrystr, iter, data):
        modelstr = completeur.get_model()[iter][0]
        return entrystr in modelstr
    completion.set_match_func(match_anywhere, None)

    # boilerplate
    window = Gtk.Window()
    window.add(entry)

    window.connect('destroy', lambda w: Gtk.main_quit())
    window.show_all()
    Gtk.main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I propose a solution in answer, sorry for my lack of experience, i just wish to help those looking a bit too much like me :)

Comment: Wh.. what's your question?

Comment: You may want to look into [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Also, properly format your question. The title is absolutely meaningless while it should shortly describe the problem. And these `SOLUTION` blocks are duplicated and misleading. If you wanted to help other people solve problem you faced, your question should contain problem description and `SOLUTION` should be posted as an answer. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for details.

Comment: [Self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) is encouraged while both question and answer are properly formatted.

Comment: Hi, That's right, sorry for my poor english ! :)

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: Capital letters are taken into accountwith the crossing 'modelstr.lower ()' of the return ...

```py
    def match_anywhere(completeur, entrystr, iter, data):
        modelstr = completeur.get_model()[iter][0]
        return entrystr in modelstr.lower()
    completion.set_match_func(match_anywhere, None)
```